# Git on Jenkins does not clone but does not fail

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

We have are using Jenkins with Gitlab/git lite with Jenkins as a CI server. We had it all working nicely on a different set of servers but have recently migrated to a new set of servers. SSH keys have been copied, Jenkins config copied and restored.

When a job is now running on one of the new agents, it starts git trying to clone the repo and get this far

```
Started by user anonymous
Building remotely on jenk-agt-w01 in workspace d:\project
Checkout:project / d:\project - hudson.remoting.Channel@5ab1efc4:jenk-agt-w01
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 72b6ecb18151f6c68bf55a588eb07f8c92660832 (origin/master)
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git2@git.server.com:project.git
git --version
git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1
```

Then the little throbber in Jenkins sits there are spins.

On the server the folder is created and the .git folder is created but it never downloads the repo.

I can log onto the server manually and run git using the same SSH keys and it downloads in seconds. I can't log on as the Jenkins server account as I don't have the password to hand right now. I don't get an error so its hard to debug.

I'm not after an answer so much as a vector to attack this problem and make some sense of it.

Comment: Try an `sshd -d` process (a debug session for your ssh daemon on the `git.server.com` side, and see if there are any relevant message when the agent tries cloning the git repo.